# How to plot on Pandas Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a data frame called that looks like this.
It is called `p1plot1`:

```
         0
0   139245
1   125395
2   116835
3    85170
4    58075
5    40050
```

I want to create a bar plot with the integers on the x axis and the values on the y axis. I tried using:

```
p1plot1.plot(kind='bar')
```

And got the output:

```
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x1fec7ca10>
```

How do I get an actual image file with the plot? Was I supposed to import something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the non-interactive mode, you need to use [show](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) to display the image

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plt.plot something

plt.show()
```

If you want to display the figure as you plot it, turn it into interactive mode

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

# plt.plot something
```

Answer (score 1):

Finish up with

```
show()
```

to display.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Ipython notebook with

```
--pylab=inline
```

Then all of your plots will be shown inline